# What is happening with this code - IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am developing a camera application which can detect rectangles in video feed and I found a sample project anyhow. But there is a thing that I still can not understand what is happening in there.

**Here is the code**

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate 
{
    var applyFilter: ((CIImage) -> CIImage?)?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad();

        applyFilter = {
            image in
            return self.performRectangleDetection(image);
        }
    }

    func performRectangleDetection(image: CIImage) -> CIImage? {

        //code returns CIImage
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        let opaqueBuffer = Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer>.passUnretained(imageBuffer!).toOpaque();
        let pixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(opaqueBuffer).takeUnretainedValue();
        let sourceImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: nil);
        let detectionResult = applyFilter?(sourceImage);
    }
}
```

This is not the full code actually.I put necessary parts only.
Can someone please explain me what is happening with the variable **applyFilter**. Is it a closure? if it is a closure what is the purpose of using a closure here.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edited:** I just need to know whether there is a special behaviour other than just using a function call

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Swift Closure docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)? That being said, the usage of a closure here seems completely redundant. It's just calling a function. I guess it would make sense if the object changed the closure throughout it's lifespan to re-direct to different filters.

Comment: @originaluser2 Yaa, I went through the doc. But I am a little bit confused about why something like this  is used in here instead of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `applyFilter` can point to a closure or function which takes a `CIImage` as a parameter and returns a `CIImage`. In the `viewDidLoad()` method, this variable is actually being set to a closure, which simply calls another method, passing it the image that was being passed in, and simply returning the return value of that method. So in this case the closure is completely unnecessary, since it is never set to anything else (unless somewhere in the code you didn't include, it gets changed to something different). In any place that calls the `applyFilter` closure, it could instead just call `performRectangleDetection` instead.

Now if keeping `applyFilter` is still desired, perhaps because you do actually set it to something different somewhere else in the code, then its usage in `viewDidLoad()` can still be simplified. The signature of `applyFilter` is the same as that of `performRectangleDetection`, so instead of the code you have:

```
applyFilter = {
    image in
    return self.performRectangleDetection(image);
}
```

You could instead just replace that with:

```
applyFilter = performRectangleDetection
```

What this does is makes the `applyFilter` variable point to the `performRectangleDetection` method directly, avoiding the intermediate closure that is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.